# Preventing bot from disconnecting users from normal voice channels?

Tags: python, discord, python-3.7, discord.py

I'm trying to get my discord bot to disconnect users who get moved to the AFK channel. all works well with that except it tries to disconnect users who just enter talk channels, not just when you get moved to the AFK channel. I have to set permissions to not allow the bot to move or disconnect from those channels, so it keeps pulling up Missing permissions. Would love it to ignore those other voice channels.

i'm not sure how to exclude a voice channel so I tried

```
if discord.VoiceChannel.id == id:
   return
```

to no avail. I've tried setting the bot to not see those channels through discord but it still does and still tries to disconnect people.

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member = discord.Member, before = discord.VoiceState.channel, after = discord.VoiceState.afk):
    await member.move_to(channel = None, reason = None)
```

Im guessing it's something basic but not sure how to ignore the other channels.
I thought the API said the `before = discord.VoiceState.channel` refers to a members recent voice channel, none if they weren't in one, then when they go to the AFK channel, `after = discord.VoiceState.afk` it would disconnect. Am i interpreting that wrong? I'm obviously missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state_update#discord.on_voice_state_update), `on_voice_state_update` will give you three things:

- The `member` who had changed their voice state
- The `VoiceState` *before* the member did something.
- The `VoiceState` **after** the member did something.

And by "did something", its means this:

- The member joins a voice channel.
- The member leaves the voice channel.
- The member muted or deafened himself.
- The member got deafened or muted by another person.

(Aka literally what the API states)

What you are looking out for is the [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state_update#discord.VoiceState) *after* the change has occured. And in the API, it states that `VoiceState` has a property called [`afk`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state_update#discord.VoiceState.afk) which checks if the member is in the afk channel.

Your code would look something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    # If the user moved to the afk channel.
    if after.afk:
        # Do something about the user in afk channel.

    ### Use the codes below if you want to check if the user moved to a channel of the ID:


    if after.channel is None:
        # The user just simply left the channel. 
        # (Aka he did not switch to another voice channel.)
    elif after.channel.id == ID_OF_CHANNEL_HERE:
        # Do something about the user that just joined the channel with the respective ID
```

Comment: Seems to work, although, when user moves to AFK channel, it disconnects them, then says `if after.channel.id == 521373272475041817:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Edit: I'm putting a return under the voice channels that I want the bot to ignore

Comment: @BrandonWeeks `after.channel` will be null if the user simply left the channel. The error occurs due to the fact that this command invokes even if the user simply left a voice channel without joining the other. (And you kicking the user out of a voice-channel invoked it), I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What about reading the docs? [Here it is](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#voice)
My idea is that you can do

```py
if discord.VoiceClient.channel.id == id:
    return
```

But I have a feeling this is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the discord.py official discord server? You will get a better and quicker answer on that than on stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, I've been there. The reference you gave me is for the old async dpy, I use the new rewrite version - dpy version 1.2.3

Comment: I thought the one I sent was the new one, I thought they updated it but sorry that I wasted your time.